# Как сверстать такой background image c внутренней рамкой?

Tags: html, css, border, background-image

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача сверстать такой background c внутренней рамкой, ссылка на макет https://www.figma.com/file/SB9yy4U3zdpzxaxjEpguHw/Sofi-de-Marko?node-id=178%3A2

Comment: А что у вас не получилось? где ваш код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Объяснения на словах - не лучший способ донести мысль, приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```